# Scaffold Drawer to showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter

At the homescreen of `myApp()` I have a stateless widget, it contains a `MaterialApp` and a `Scaffold`. Scaffold have a property of `drawer` and I passed I created a drawer, and one of the item in my drawer needs to open the `showModalBottomSheet` while closing the `drawer`. How can I achieve this? I've tried passing the `context` itself, and as `globalKey.currentContext` (after `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> globalKey = GlobalKey();`) but the drawer sometimes closes, other time gives me a `NoMethodFoundException` (or something like that)

In short, how to have a `Scaffold drawer` that have one of the item, when tapped closes the `drawer` and `showModalBottomSheet`?

Current code:

```
class Timeline extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> homeScaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Test",
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black)),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        key: homeScaffoldKey,
        drawer: showDrawer(homeScaffoldKey.currentContext),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            HomePageView(),
            AppBar(
              elevation: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Drawer showDrawer(BuildContext context) {
  void showCalendarsModalBottom() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext builder) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: repo.calendars.length,
          itemBuilder: (builder, index) {
            return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (builder, StateSetter setState) => ListTile(
                leading: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Checkbox(
                      value: repo.getIsEnabledCal(repo.getCal(index)),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          repo.toggleCalendar(repo.getCal(index));
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 14,
                      width: 14,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 6),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      repo.getCal(index).name,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    repo.toggleCalendar(repo.getCal(index));
                  });
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  return Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        DrawerHeader(
          child: Align(
            child: Text('Timeline', textScaleFactor: 2),
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Dark Mode'),
          onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Calenders'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);

            showCalendarsModalBottom();
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you include a code snippet of your app?

Comment: added code snippit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated working code based on your code snippet:

You'll need to have `statefulwidget` that will help to pass the context from drawer to bottomsheet and pass the `context` as an argument in `showCalendarModalBottomSheet()` method.

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: Timeline(), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false));
}

class Timeline extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Test",
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black)),
      ),
     home: MyHomePage()
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        drawer: AppDrawer(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            //HomePageView(),
            AppBar(
              elevation: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            )
          ],
        )
      );
    }

    Widget AppDrawer() {
      return Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Align(
                child: Text('Timeline', textScaleFactor: 2),
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Dark Mode'),
              onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Calenders'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                showCalendarsModalBottom(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    Future<Null> showCalendarsModalBottom(context) {
      return showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        // your code here
      ));
    }
  }
```

And the output is: When app drawer menu Calendar is tapped, it closes and opens the bottomsheet seamlessly. If you tap on app drawer again and repeat steps, you see smooth transition between drawer and bottomsheet. Hope this answers your question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `context` in `Navigator.of(context).pop();` is giving me error (based on your previous code)

Comment: Thank you for helping out. One more thing, do you thing my code is unorganized? cuz it seems so, from a length and maintenance stand point.

Comment: Does it need to be stateful? It's not actually using `setState`.